# Passing array of structs with reference - segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct X {
    char surname[30];
    int deg;
};

void read_record(struct X** a, int size){
    for (int i = 0;i < size; i++){
        a[i]->deg = 0;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n = 10;
    struct X *container = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof(struct X) * n);
    read_record(&container, n);
}
```

I created a 1D array of size `n`, then I passed it by reference to the function `read_record`. However, when I execute the program, there is a segmentation fault. What is the problem?

**EDIT:**

As a next step, I want to reallocate the array of 10 elements in the function with size of `20`. That's why I want to send the array as a reference. If I did it in `main` then I would write:

```
container = realloc(container, (n + 10) * sizeof(Struct X));
```

How can I do this in the function?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: @SouravGhosh this is not the problem.

Comment: and that is why that's a comment, not an answer!

Comment: In the `main` function `container` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `X` structures. You need to pass this pointer *as is* to the function. Basically, what the argument declaration `struct X** a` is saying is that `a` is an array of pointers to `X` structures". But that is not what you are passing in the call.

Comment: If you opt to keep passing pointer to pointer, you need to dereference that pointer to get the original pointer: `(*a)[i].deg = 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`container` is already a pointer, you don't need to pass the address-of the pointer, instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct X {
    char surname[30];
    int deg;
};

void read_record(struct X *a, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i].deg = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t n = 10;
    struct X *container = malloc(sizeof(struct X) * n);

    read_record(container, n);
}
```

also, prefer `size_t` to store the number of allocated objects.

Nitpick: `read_record` doesn't seem a good name for a function that modifies the contents of the records.

*EDIT: As a next step, I want to reallocate the array of 10 elements in the function with size of 20. (in the function). That's why I want to send the array as a reference.*

Same approach but returning a reallocated `container`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct X {
    char surname[30];
    int deg;
};

struct X *read_record(struct X *a, size_t size)
{
    struct X *new = realloc(a, sizeof(struct X) * size);

    if (new != NULL)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            new[i].deg = 0;
        }
    }
    return new;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t n = 10;
    struct X *container = malloc(sizeof(struct X) * n);

    container = read_record(container, n * 2);
    if (container == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't read record\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidRanieri actually I want also to reallocate the container in the function, that's why I passed it as a reference.

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis reallocate with which size? you are passing 10 and the container is already storing 10 elements.

Comment: @DavidRanieri As a next step, I want to reallocate the array of 10 elements in the function with size of 20. (in the function). That's why I want to send the array as a reference.

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis this invalidates all the answers, but you have an edit

Answer (score 2):

> As a next step, I want to reallocate the array of 10 elements in the function with size of 20. (in the function). That's why I want to send the array as a reference.

The pointer is passed by value, so to save the changes and have them usable outside the function scope, after the function ends, i.e. in `main`, a pointer to pointer must be the argument, and the address of the pointer must be passed, your overall assessment is correct.

Your implementation, however, is not correct, here's how you shoud do it:

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/af9Kfe)</kbd>

```
void read_record(struct X **a, int size) //double pointer
{
    *a = realloc(*a, sizeof **a * (size + 10)); //reallocate memory for 20 ints

    if (*a == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size + 10; i++) //assing new values
    {
        (*a)[i].deg = 1;
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    struct X *container = malloc(sizeof *container * n); //original allocation
    //the pointer now has space for 10 ints

    if (container == NULL)
    { //check allocation errors
        perror("malloc");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //assign values
    {
        container[i].deg = 0;
    }
    
    read_record(&container, n); //pass by reference
    //the pointer now has space for 20 ints
    
}
```

Alternatively you can return the pointer instead, refering to [David Ranieri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64387639/6865932).

Comment: Why? there is no need to use fragmented memory.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I guess I somewhat missread the question, returning the pointer is a solid solution, I corrected my answer and posted this allocation done with double pointer as an alternative to your good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first function parameter has the pointer to pointer type `struct X**`.  So dereferencing the parameter `a` you will get a pointer of the type `struct X*`. Now you may apply the subscript operator that yields lvalue of the type `struct X`..

That is the function definition will look like

```
void read_record(struct X** a,int size){
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        ( *a )[i].deg = 0;
    }
}
```

Or this statement

```
( *a )[i].deg = 0;
```

may be substituted for this statement

```
a[0][i].deg = 0;
```

On the other hand, there is no great sense to declare the first parameter as having the type `struct X**`. The function can look simpler as for example

```
void read_record(struct X* a,int size){
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        a[i].deg = 0;
    }
}
```

and be called like

```
read_record( container, n );
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `read_record` you pass a pointer to a pointer to the first element of an array of `X` structures.

But inside the `read_record` you treat it as a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to `X` structures (i.e. as an array of pointers to `X`). There's a subtle but very important difference here.

If you want to emulate pass-by-reference for the pointer variable, you need to dereference it inside the `read_record` to get the original pointer (and remember that then you have an array of objects, not pointers):

```
(*a)[i].deg = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Double pointer is the problem. The code should be:

```
void read_record(struct X* a,int size){ // Check the change
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        a[i]->deg = 0;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n = 10;
    struct X *container=(struct X*)malloc(sizeof(struct X)*n);
    read_record(container,n); // Check the change
}
```